# What does /*[[${}]]*/ means in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm analysing(debugging) someone else's JavaScript code. I'm not a friend of JavaScript.

What does following code means?

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" th:unless="${success}">
$(function() {
        var code = /*[[${returnCode}]]*/"",
                message = /*[[${returnMessage}]]*/"";
        alert(message);
        self.close();
});
</script>
```

1. What does `/*[[${variable}]]*/` means? Is it just a comment?
2. What does the comma(`,`) at the end of `var code =` statement? Is it [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)?
3. What value the `message` variable has?
4. Does `alert(message)` actually take an action?

Comment: 1) a comment--unless you're dealing with some special framework that does something to parse out and replace these, in which case you'll need to tell us which framework 2) commas separate delcarations in single `var` statements 3) `message` is an empty string 4) yes, it opens an empty alert box 5) this is all basic JS syntax available in any entry level documentation

Comment: no it's not the comma operator.

Comment: It looks like some data put in the file for a third party tool to read, like a type checker, or a documentation generator. It's also possible those are variables that are populated when the page is rendered. Those lines are valid Javascript but it's just inline comments.

Comment: I actually run your code in console, and easily find that both code and message is empty string...did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**▶ 1<sup>st</sup> Question:**

Everything inside **`/* */`** is considered a comment in *JavaScript*, *PHP*, *CSS* and most likely more languages that I'm not aware of.

There are some programs, however, that use the content inside comments, if it's appropriate, to turn on/off settings, such as JSLint and even Stack Overflow's snippets.

---

**▶ 2<sup>nd</sup> Question:**

Instead of declaring variables like:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 3;
var c = 8;
var d = 17;
```

You can separate them by comma, thus using a single **`var`** keyword:

```
var a = 0,
    b = 3,
    c = 8,
    d = 17;
```

---

**▶ 3<sup>rd</sup> Question:**

Both the **`code`** and **`message`** variables contain the empty string.

```
code= "";
message = "";
```

---

**▶ 4<sup>th</sup> Question:**

The alert works as usual without, though, showing any message.

[image]